# Fastest way to compute upper-triangular matrix of geometric series (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, linear-algebra

and thanks in advance for the help.

Using Python (mostly numpy), I am trying to compute an upper-triangular matrix where each row "j" is the first j-terms of a geometric series, all rows using the same parameter.

For example, if my parameter is B (where abs(B)=<1, i.e. B in [-1,1]), then row 1 would be [1 B B^2 B^3 ... B^(N-1)], row 2 would be [0 1 B B^2...B^(N-2)] ... row N would be [0 0 0 ... 1].

This computation is key to a Bayesian Metropolis-Gibbs sampler, and so needs to be done thousands of times for new values of "B".

I have currently tried this two ways:

Method 1 - Mostly Vectorized:

```
B_Matrix = np.triu(np.dot(np.reshape(B**(-1*np.array(range(N))),(N,1)),np.reshape(B**(np.array(range(N))),(1,N))))
```

Essentially, this is the upper triangle part of a product of an Nx1 and 1xN set of matrices:

upper triangle ([1 B^(-1) B^(-2) ... B^(-(N-1))]' * [1 B B^2 B^3 ... B^(N-1)])

This works great for small N (algebraically it is correct), but for large N it errs out. And it produces errors out for B=0 (which should be allowed). I believe this is stemming from taking B^(-N) ~ inf for small B and large N.

Method 2:

```
B_Matrix = np.zeros((N,N))
B_Row_1 = B**(np.array(range(N)))
for n in range(N):
    B_Matrix[n,n:] = B_Row_1[0:N-n]
```

So that just fills in the matrix row by row, but uses a loop which slows things down.

I was wondering if anyone had run into this before, or had any better ideas on how to compute this matrix in a faster way.

I've never posted on stackoverflow before, but didn't see this question anywhere, and thought I'd ask.

Let me know if there's a better place to ask this, and if I should provide anymore detail.

Comment: I think the first question you have to ask yourself here is: How fast do I have to get? If you want the version with the loops (probably faster in the end), you may want to check how fast you can get with a completely statically typed  `cython` function. If that's not enough, you still have the option to write this function entirely in `C` and integrate it  into your python code.

Comment: Edited the rows, thanks! And I guess I need to check out cython, I have no experience but I've heard it can make things faster.

Comment: Will this array be used "read-only", or will you make changes to it in-place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`scipy.linalg.toeplitz`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.toeplitz.html):

```
In [12]: n = 5

In [13]: b = 0.5

In [14]: toeplitz(b**np.arange(n), np.zeros(n)).T
Out[14]: 
array([[ 1.    ,  0.5   ,  0.25  ,  0.125 ,  0.0625],
       [ 0.    ,  1.    ,  0.5   ,  0.25  ,  0.125 ],
       [ 0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.5   ,  0.25  ],
       [ 0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.5   ],
       [ 0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ]])
```

If your use of the array is strictly "read only", you can play tricks with numpy strides to quickly create an array that uses only 2*n-1 elements (instead of n^2):

```
In [55]: from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

In [56]: def make_array(b, n):
   ....:     vals = np.zeros(2*n - 1)
   ....:     vals[n-1:] = b**np.arange(n)
   ....:     a = as_strided(vals[n-1:], shape=(n, n), strides=(-vals.strides[0], vals.strides[0]))
   ....:     return a
   ....: 

In [57]: make_array(0.5, 4)
Out[57]: 
array([[ 1.   ,  0.5  ,  0.25 ,  0.125],
       [ 0.   ,  1.   ,  0.5  ,  0.25 ],
       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  1.   ,  0.5  ],
       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  1.   ]])
```

If you will modify the array in-place, make a copy of the result returned by `make_array(b, n)`.  That is, `arr = make_array(b, n).copy()`.

The function `make_array2` incorporates the suggestion @Jaime made in the comments:

```
In [30]: def make_array2(b, n):
   ....:     vals = np.zeros(2*n-1)
   ....:     vals[n-1] = 1
   ....:     vals[n:] = b
   ....:     np.cumproduct(vals[n:], out=vals[n:])
   ....:     a = as_strided(vals[n-1:], shape=(n, n), strides=(-vals.strides[0], vals.strides[0]))
   ....:     return a
   ....: 

In [31]: make_array2(0.5, 4)
Out[31]: 
array([[ 1.   ,  0.5  ,  0.25 ,  0.125],
       [ 0.   ,  1.   ,  0.5  ,  0.25 ],
       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  1.   ,  0.5  ],
       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  1.   ]])
```

`make_array2` is more than twice as fast as `make_array`:

```
In [35]: %timeit make_array(0.99, 600)
10000 loops, best of 3: 23.4 µs per loop

In [36]: %timeit make_array2(0.99, 600)
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.7 µs per loop
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot, thanks! I had never heard of toeplitz before!

Comment: Just to follow up, it looks like the toeplitz solution is just as fast as method 2 above (just under 20 seconds to do a 600+ row version for both, 500 times). But from a clean-code standpoint I like toeplitz for sure

Comment: Thanks Warren! Both of these work, I'll run some speed tests to see if either is faster in my code. Also, I believe it is read-only, in that I need to create, then reference the matrix in each iteration, but never change anything about the matrix itself. (It's just used to help vectorize the creation of a very complicated covariance matrix, that depends on the B-parameter)

Comment: It is more verbose and obscure, but if speed is a major concern, then the following is about 10x faster for `n = 1000`. Instead of `vals[n-1:] = b**np.arange(n)`, do `vals[n-1] = 1; vals[n:] = b; np.cumproduct(vals[n:], out=vals[n:]`. A similar trick could be used with the input to `toeplitz`.